# NVIDIA Persistenced Daemon error

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, cuda

I'm trying to install CUDA 10.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 using guide from
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html
In step `7.2.1 Install Persistence Daemon`, when I execute command

> /usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced --verbose

I got an error:

`$ /usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced --verbose
nvidia-persistenced failed to initialize. Check syslog for more details.`

Log from the /var/log/syslog file:

```
May 27 19:49:42 Azurite nvidia-persistenced: Verbose syslog connection opened
May 27 19:49:42 Azurite nvidia-persistenced: Directory /var/run/nvidia-persistenced will not be removed on exit
May 27 19:49:42 Azurite nvidia-persistenced: Unable to access /var/run/nvidia-persistenced: Permission denied
May 27 19:49:42 Azurite nvidia-persistenced: Shutdown (6802)
```

Result from `nvidia-smi`:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.59       Driver Version: 440.59       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce 840M        Off  | 00000000:08:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   52C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    151MiB /  2004MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      2650      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            76MiB |
|    0      2805      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          73MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Result from `nvcc -V`

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Feb__8_19:08:17_PST_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.105
```

Is there something wrong with my CUDA Toolkit installation? Thank you.
In logs app:

```
Sender: nvidia-persiste
Message: Failed to lock PID file: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

When I run with `sudo`

```
May 27 20:20:52 Azurite nvidia-persistenced: Verbose syslog connection opened
May 27 20:20:52 Azurite nvidia-persistenced: Directory /var/run/nvidia-persistenced will not be removed on exit
May 27 20:20:52 Azurite nvidia-persistenced: Failed to lock PID file: Resource temporarily unavailable
May 27 20:20:52 Azurite nvidia-persistenced: Shutdown (8059)
```

**NOTE**: my laptop passed `7.2.3.3. Running the Binaries` on `deviceQuery` and `bandwidthTest`

Comment: The "permission denied" error in your logfile might be solved by running nvidia-persistenced with sudo.

Comment: And a simple way to install cuda toolkit is to use "sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-dev nvidia-cuda-toolkit " . If you have a software in your ubuntu repo , it's better to install it from there unless you want to use a newer version.

Comment: And please press the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1244186/edit) button and add the log you've commented to your question.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi I almost finished installing CUDA. I don't want to remove everything and start over.

Comment: Maybe there is already an instance of nvidia-persistenced. Because it says "resource temporarily unavailable".

Comment: @ParsaMousavi How do I check if there is already an instance? If there is, is that means my installation is normal/complete?

Comment: You can check that via "pgrep nvidia-persistened" or something like that. And that gives you a PID . You can kill that daemon via "kill PID "

Comment: And if you're able to use your GPU and nvcc compiler correctly then it should be correctly installed. Persistence daemon is for [initializing and de-initializing the GPU](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/driver-persistence/index.html)

Comment: @ParsaMousavi I've just checked using `htop` and there's one running with `PID 1304` and `Command /usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced --user nvidia-persistenced --no-persistence-mode --verbose`. Guess everything is OK, thank you.

Comment: Note that if the persistence daemon is running , you don't have to kill and restart it. It just works on its own. And it gets started by [systemd](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/understanding-and-using-systemd/) .So You don't have to worry about starting or stopping it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just checked using `htop` and there's one running with `PID 1304` and `Command /usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced --user nvidia-persistenced --no-persistence-mode --verbose`. Guess everything is OK, thank you.